# Convert command arguments to history search patterns

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have an alias to do quick searchs on my terminal history by just typing h + search pattern.
`alias h='history | /usr/bin/grep '`

It works like it should, but I can't add more search patterns without adding more greps
instances.
e. g. `h pacman | grep wine`

I want to adapt it to convert other possible arguments to search pattern.
e. g. `h pacman wine`

Obs.: I know there are out of the box solutions to achieve that, but since I have no idea how to do it, I want to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you'll need a shell-function instead of a shell-alias:

```bsh
function h() {
  code="cat ~/.bash_history"
  for arg in $@ ; do
    code="$code | grep $arg"
  done
  eval "$code"
}
```

You can put this function in your `.bashrc` or wherever you normally write your alias instruction.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Using "for arg in $@;" will get all my args dynamically. Great learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here is that for multiple patterns to `grep`, you usually have to use the `-e` option to specify each pattern (so `grep -e pacman -e wine` instead of just `grep pacman wine`). Two options:

1. Aliases don't support arguments, so use a function:

   ```
   h () {
       local args=()   # local array to store argument with -e for grep
       for i
       do
          args+=(-e "$i")  # tack on the -e for each argument
       done
       history | grep "${args[@]}"
   }
   ```

   This assumes all arguments will be patterns to `grep`.
2. Continue using the alias, and add the `-e` yourself:

   ```
    h -e pacman -e wine
   ```

   This way, you can also add whatever other `grep` options you want (say, e.g., `-C 3` to show some context around the results).